# Casting string to enum

Tags: c#, string, casting, enums

I'm reading file content and take string at exact location like this

```
 string fileContentMessage = File.ReadAllText(filename).Substring(411, 3);
```

Output will always be either `Ok` or `Err`

On the other side I have `MyObject` which have `ContentEnum` like this

```
public class MyObject

    {
      public enum ContentEnum { Ok = 1, Err = 2 };        
      public ContentEnum Content { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, on the client side I want to use code like this (to cast my string `fileContentMessage` to `Content` property)

```
string fileContentMessage = File.ReadAllText(filename).Substring(411, 3);

    MyObject myObj = new MyObject ()
    {
       Content = /// ///,
    };
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Enum.TryParse(string value, out variable); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Use [`Enum.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx).

```
var content = (ContentEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ContentEnum), fileContentMessage);
```

Comment: `Enum.Parse` returns an `object` which needs to be casted. I felt free to edit :)

Comment: I tried with Parity Enum and when I give the string value of 123 it returns it without issue, even though Parity enum does not include 123 value of enum

Comment: @JohnDemetriou that's documented: _"If value is the string representation of an integer that does not represent an underlying value of the enumType enumeration, the method returns an enumeration member whose underlying value is value converted to an integral type. If this behavior is undesirable, call the IsDefined method to ensure that a particular string representation of an integer is actually a member of enumType"_.

Answer (score 27):

As an extra, you can take the `Enum.Parse` answers already provided and put them in an easy-to-use static method in a helper class.

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, ignoreCase: true);
}
```

And use it like so:

```
{
   Content = ParseEnum<ContentEnum>(fileContentMessage);
};
```

Especially helpful if you have lots of (different) Enums to parse.

Comment: Thanks for the ignoreCase: true tidbit!

Answer (score 22):

.NET 4.0+ has a generic [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
ContentEnum content;
Enum.TryParse(fileContentMessage, out content);
```

Answer (score 18):

Have a look at using something like

[Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one
>   or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object. A
>   parameter specifies whether the operation is case-sensitive. The
>   return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

or

[Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one
>   or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.