# How to call a common function in a class instance?

Tags: c#

Let's say i have two classes:

```
class Batman
{
    public void Robin(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}

class Superman
{
    public void Kryptonie(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}
```

Now, I have an instance of those classes:

```
public object Crossover()
{
     var batman = new Batman();
     var superman = new Superman();

     return superman;
}
```

I do not know instance of which class the Crossover will return, it could be Batman or Superman.

```
var someVariableName = Crossover(); //I don't know if this contains an instance of Superman or Batman;

//I do know that no matter which class instance is returned, it will always contain a function named Jump which i want to trigger:
someVariableName.Jump();
```

Now i know i could do something like:

```
if (someVariableName.GetType() == typeof(Superman)) 
{
    ((Superman) someVariableName).Jump()
}
```

But is there a way to trigger the Jump function without having to manually check for each type with if..else.., when i know that the instance of the class saved in that variable will always contain a Jump function?

Comment: as `Crossover` return `object`, this code `var someVariableName = Crossover(); someVariableName.Jump();` just will not compile. It's better to create `interface IJumpingEntity { void Jump()}`, make `Batman` and `Superman` implementing this interface and return object of interface type from `Crossover`

Comment: What if you had a base class that Batman and Superman both inherited from, put the Jump method in that class, and then had Crossover return an object of the base class type?

Comment: Dear 15K+ rep answerers, are you sure this question is unique? Shouldn't you spent a few seconds finding a reference question instead of answering it?

Comment: @CodeCaster This one has super heros though.

Comment: @CodeCaster, [yeah like you do that all the time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13970279/2711965).

Comment: @user2711965 that was two years ago. People learn. You're right though, that one should be closed as duplicate of [How do I Convert a string to an enum in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-enum-in-c).

Comment: @CodeCaster: You are right. But there is no fun in closing a question. Answering is though...

Comment: @Patrick thanks for editing and closing that one! :) Keeping the site clean. As more and more questions already are answered, I get more fun from finding duplicates than from typing answers that are already there. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: True. Getting off-topic but my closing-super powers are quite fun indeed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where interfaces become useful.  Consider this interface:

```
public interface ISuperhero
{
    void Jump();
}
```

And these implementations:

```
class Batman : ISuperhero
{
    public void Robin(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}

class Superman : ISuperhero
{
    public void Kryptonie(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}
```

They're individual implementations, but they share a common polymorphic interface.  Your function can then return that interface:

```
public ISuperhero Crossover()
{
     var batman = new Batman();
     var superman = new Superman();

     return superman;
}
```

Since that interface has a `Jump()` method, it can be called directly:

```
var someVariableName = Crossover();
someVariableName.Jump();
```

Answer (score 14):

Use an interface:

```
interface ISuperHero
{
    void Jump();
}

class Batman : ISuperHero
{
    public void Robin(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}

class Superman : ISuperHero
{
    public void Kryptonie(){...}
    public void Jump(){...}
}
```

Then return the interface from your method:

```
public ISuperHero Crossover()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a base class defining the method (or an interface, if it is just about the method definition). You can override the implementation in the deriving classes then.

```
abstract class ActionFigure
{
    public abstract void Jump(); // just define it has a Jump method, but implement it in the deriving class

    public void SomethingGeneral()
    {
        // no need for an override, just implement it here
    }
}

class Batman : ActionFigure
{
    public void Robin(){...}
    public override void Jump(){...}
}

class Superman : ActionFigure
{
    public void Kryptonie(){...}
    public override void Jump(){...}
}
```