# How to get int value of Enum by providing string value in varibale

Tags: asp.net, enums

Here is my code for Enum:

```
enum Tempurature 
{ 
    Low = 2, 
    Medium, 
    High, 
};

Temperature value = Tempurature.Medium; 
int val = (int)value; 
Console.WriteLine("Temperature value is.." + val);

Output is : Temperature value is.. 3
```

Now I want same output as 3 but instead of providing **Tempurature.Medium**, I want to send Medium in variable value.
How can i do this?
Is this possible or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting string to enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970257/casting-string-to-enum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the string into the enum type `Temperature`:

```
Tempurature temperature = (Tempurature)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(Tempurature), "Medium", true);
Console.WriteLine("Temperature value is.." + (int)temperature);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `value`

```
Console.WriteLine("Temperature value is.." + value);
```